# How to use in-mem HSQLDB sequences with unit testing?

Tags: spring, junit, hsqldb

My application uses sequences, and I'm trying to set up junit test environment with HSQLDB in-mem database that would have a similar setup. This is how I've configured the sequences and their creation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="true"
      destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="logSeqIncrementer" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.HsqlSequenceMaxValueIncrementer">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="incrementerName" value="public.agent_logs_seq" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="offerSeqIncrementer" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.HsqlSequenceMaxValueIncrementer">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="incrementerName" value="public.offers_seq" />
    </bean>
    <jdbc:embedded-database
        id="test"
        type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script
            location="classpath:/create-ddl.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>   
</beans>
```

And contents of create-ddl.sql:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.agent_logs_seq;
```

Results in

```
java.sql.SQLException: Sequence already exists in statement
```

but if I comment that out, I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected exception:
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:
    Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is
java.sql.SQLException: Sequence not found:
    AGENT_LOGS_SEQ in statement [call next value for public.agent_logs_seq]
```

The way I'm trying to use the sequence:

```
DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer incrementer =
    (DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer) context.getBean("logSeqIncrementer");
Integer logId = Integer.valueOf(incrementer.nextIntValue());
```

Edit: changed the details above so that correct sequence class would be used. It didn't solve the issue, however.

Comment: Near the end, you say "but then trying to use it results in <error message>". How do you use the sequence?

Comment: What will be if you try to create tables for sequence, like `create table agents_logs_seq (value identity); insert into agents_logs_seq values(0);`

Comment: @php-coder as I now changed the sequence class, this should not be necessary, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem which is raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780493/missing-sequences-in-hsql-for-testing).

There were various solutions offered. The H2 Database seemed interesting. In the end I manually dropped and then create the sequences in a script.

Comment: Tested and creating manually in @Before method works. Don't really like going this way, but have to accept, don't have better options for now :)

Answer (score 3):

You have specified `org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.HsqlMaxValueIncrementer` as the class, however, it seems Spring is using `HsqlSequenceMaxValueIncrementer` (in the same package) and creates a SEQUENCE, instead of a TABLE.

The `HsqlMaxValueIncrementer` is an older implementation which is suitable for database platforms that do not support SEQUENCE objects. The `HsqlSequenceMaxValueIncrementer` is more recent (Spring v. 2.5) and is the more efficient choice for HSQLDB. This should create the SEQUENCE objects you specified and then use `NEXT VALUE FOR public.agents_logs_seq` internally to retrieve the next sequence value.

Comment: Wow, I'd never would've figured that one out. Thank you. I changed that, but now I'm getting "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Sequence already exists in statement [CREATE SEQUENCE public.agent_logs_seq]" for the creation, and when I comment that out, I get "Unexpected exception: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Sequence not found: AGENT_LOGS_SEQ in statement [call next value for public.agent_logs_seq]". I'll update the question, too.