# How do I spin up a MySQL database in Maven for use with our JUnit tests?

Tags: mysql, maven, testing, junit, liquibase

We're using Maven 3.0.3, MySql 5.5, JUnit 4.8.1, and Liquibase.  Here's what we would like to do.  I would like to spin up a MySQL database, run our liquibase database scripts against it, and then run our JUnit tests, using this newly-created database as the datasource.  If someone knows of a way to do this using Maven, know that any sample script you post will get more votes than you know what to do with -- and the respect you so dearly deserve.

I realize that the H2 in-memory database supports a MySQL mode, but we don't want to use that.  We want to get as close to the real thing as possible.

Comment: Check out [this (How to initialize in memory hsqld using spring via script)][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329283/how-to-initialize-in-memory-hsqldb-using-script-via-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Use the [Maven SQL plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) to create a database.
2. Use the [Maven liquibase plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven) to run your scripts.
3. Run your tests (standard surefire).
4. Use the Maven SQL plugin again to drop the database, so you can start fresh the next time.

Comment: Very interesting!  I'm going to play around with this to see if I can get it to do what I want.