# Specify url of jdbc:embedded-database

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I want to specify the URL for the `jdbc:embedded-database` tag. Is this not possible?

For example, if I have the following in my context:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="classpath:com/example/init.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

It will create an in memory database located at `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource`

What I want to do is be able to have a different bean ID and database name...

For example:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource" url="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb">
    <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="classpath:com/example/init.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using jdbc:embedded-database, you can do it with a normal datasource configuration, and spring support for SQL script execution

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc\:hsqldb\:mem\:YOUNAME" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>


<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema_h2.sql" />
 </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: I did not know about `jdbc:initialize-database`. This should work perfectly, Thanks!